# Do Bulgarians or Sri Lankans need transit visas for Serbia or Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit-visas, serbia, sri-lankan-citizens, abu-dhabi, bulgarian-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan citizen with a Bulgarian wife and a Bulgarian residence card for family members. I work in Germany and so additionally have a German residence permit.

My wife and I are going from Bulgaria to Sri Lanka via Belgrade and Abu Dhabi. We have a transit in Belgrade of 7h and 30min in both directions, and will remain inside the airport.

Will we need transit visas?

Answer (score 3):

The following info is from Timatic, the database used by airlines:

[**For your wife**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=bg&DE=LK&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=rs&TR=ae&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

For Belgrade:

> VISA NOT REQUIRED

For Abu Dhabi:

> VISA NOT REQUIRED

For Sri Lanka:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Bulgaria can obtain a
>   visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30 days.

So, your wife needs **no visas** at all.

[**For you**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=lk&DE=LK&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=de&TR=rs&TR=ae&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

For Belgrade:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours

(you can even leave the airport and visit Belgrade, by presenting your passport and German residence permit)

For Abu Dhabi:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours

For Sri Lanka:

> VISA NOT REQUIRED

So you need **no visas** at all.